# What is the correct notion of unique factorization in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I was recently writing some notes on basic commutative ring theory, and was trying to convince myself why it was a good idea to study integral domains when it comes to unique factorization.

If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $a$ is a zero divisor, we cannot expect $a$ generally to have unique factorization in the ordinary sense, seen for example by the fact that $2*4=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

But this only makes me think that instead of focusing on domains, we should just focus on element that aren't zero divisors. Indeed, we can let $R_z$ be the set of elements that aren't zero divisors. Then if $R$ is nontrivial, $R_z$ is a commutative monoid under multiplication that contains the units. Moreover $R_z$ has the nice property that any if $a_1\dots a_n = b$ is some factorization of $b \in R_z$, then all the $a_i$ are in $R_z$.

In this setting, we can say that $R$ having unique factorization means that $R_z/R^\times$ is a free commutative monoid. In the case that $R$ is a domain, this agrees with the definition of a UFD.

Now standard arguments about factorization of nonzero elements in domains seem to work just as well for $R_z$. For example in a Noetherian ring, every element of $R_z$ can be factored into some irreducibles times a unit.

Similarly, the proof seems to go through that principle ideal rings are unique factorization rings (in my sense).

So my questions are:

Is what I'm saying correct? If so, why do we normally restrict to domains when many arguments go through for arbitrary rings with no more effort (as long as we are willing to ignore zero-divisors)? Are there other natural generalizations of unique factorization **of elements** of a ring for which analogous theorems can be proven without more difficulty?

By looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797291/study-of-irreducibility-for-rings-that-are-not-integral-domains) question, I found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.3977.pdf) and [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927879908826543), which did have examples of generalizations of unique factorization to more general rings. The first one essentially considers a tame type of ring where zero divisors are not so bad in terms of factorization, and my impression of the second one is that it exerts a lot of effort trying to generalize the notion of unique factorization to the extent that it becomes significantly more complicated.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your second link directs to `http://this/`.

Comment: Ah, whoops, it is now fixed

Comment: I have never really thought about this much. But an important question to ask is: What situations will the generalized notion be useful in?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is it really? You can do mathematics bottom-up and just see what happens. Going from integral domains to general commutative rings is not a wild abstraction. You basically stay within the same language. I know I’ve come across some interesting insights by considering some mild generalisations or abstractions.

Comment: @k.stm You can, sure. But usually you need at least some idea of why you might want to do so.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft To explore a cave, you don’t need to have an idea of what to find inside. If the entrance looks promising, that may be enough to get you going. And doing so may turn out worthwhile even if you have had no clue of what to expect. And I’d say that’s the difference between exploration and examination. So personally, I find the question promising. The only thing Ishan Levy asked is whether there is some obvious reason to *not* explore it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are right, though. I agree that asking “Where will this be useful?” is important. It’s just not *that* important. Having no answer to this question is no reason to not go further.

Comment: @k.stm I did not mean it as a prerequisite to study this. I meant it as a way to figure out which direction is more likely to be interesting (i.e. which generalization to consider).

Comment: Perhaps also of interest: [Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero Divisors](http://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181072068) by Anderson and Valdes-Leon (similar to your second linked paper, but open access).

Comment: [Bill Dubuque gives a few links worth mentioning in this context](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/11619). I found my way there when we discussed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2511040/11619). User lhf gives other links there that you may also find interesting.

Comment: I guess the example $(x+2)(x+3) = (x-1)x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$ shows that UFRs are bad in that they are neither closed under products ($\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$) nor under adjoining elements (since $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is a PIR), two nice properties one might have hoped for

Answer (score 7):

This is likely more a contribution to what you are looking for than a precise answer to your question.

As unique factorization properties have little to do with the addition of the ring, let me switch to commutative monoids. Let $H$ be commutative monoid and let $\leq$ be the division preorder, defined by
$$
  a \leqslant b \iff \text{there exists $x \in H$ such that $ax = b$}
$$
Let us assume that $\leqslant$ is actually a partial order. Irreducible and prime elements can now be defined as follows.

**Definition 1**. An element $x \in H$ is *irreducible* if, for each finite set $I$ such that $x = \prod_{i \in I}x_i$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $x_i = x$.

Note that $1$ is not irreducible since $1 = \prod_{i \in \emptyset}x_i$.

**Definition 2**. An element $x \in H$ is *prime* if, for each finite set $I$ such that $x \leqslant \prod_{i \in I}x_i$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $x_i \leqslant x$.

In the join semilattice represented below, $1$, $p$, $q$ and $r$ are irreducible; $p$ et $q$ are prime but $r$ is not. All elements are idempotent.

$\hskip 125pt$[image]

**Definition 3**. A decomposition of an element $x$ is a finite family $D = (x_i)_{i \in I}$ of irreducible elements such that $x = \prod_{i \in I}x_i$.

**Definition 4**. Let $D = (x_i)_{i \in I}$ and $D' = (x'_i)_{i \in I'}$ be two decompositions of $x$. Then $D$ is *more reduced than* $D'$ if there is an injective map $\sigma:I \to I'$ such that, for all $i \in I$, $x_i \leqslant x'_{\sigma(i)}$.

Here is the main definition.

**Definition 5**. A monoid $H$ is *factorial* if, for each element $x \in H$, 
the set of decompositions of $x$ has a minimum element, called the *reduced decomposition* of $x$.

Here is a nontrivial example, with both an infinite ascending and descending chain. This is again a join semilattice.
The irreducible elements are $a$, $b$, the $x_n$'s and the $y_n$'s. There are only two prime elements: $a$ and $y_1$. Indeed $y_2$, for instance, is not prime since $y_2\leqslant ay_1 = x$ but $y_2 \not\leqslant a$ and $y_2 \not\leqslant y_1$. The reduced decomposition of $x$ is $x = ay_1$.

$\hskip 100pt$[image]

What can be proved with this notion? The main result is that factorial monoids have lcm's , but not necessarily gcd's. Furthermore, if $H$ is factorial, then $(H, \text{lcm})$ is also factorial.

**Reference**. This material is from this (French and poorly written) [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00017719/fr/).

Comment: Is it *irreductible* or *irreducible*? Because in $ℤ$, $2 = (-2)(-1)$, so $2$ would not be irreducible or irreductible …

Comment: irreducible. Thanks for pointing out this typo.

Comment: In $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$, $\leqslant$ is not an order, since $1 \mid -1$ and $-1 \mid 1$.

Comment: I find this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848581/lattice-theoretic-interpretation-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic/848781#848781